# Android listview content view not created

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I've got android activity with bottom navigation menu.
when I click on one of the item on bottom navigation bar, the listfragment is shown on top of activity. The list fragment could be closed in two ways.
1.click on the activity (somewhere in activity) - this works
2.click on another item (not the one where list fragment was initialised)

for ex: I click on item 4, it pops up little list fragment on top of activity.
when I click on activity, it closes the list fragment.
but when I click on item 1, it throws error that "Content view not yet created"

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_more_technician, container, false);
     return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   // ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
     //       R.array.tech_array, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "inside  of on activity created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ArrayAdapter mBTAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tech_array)) {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            // Get the Layout Parameters for ListView Current Item View
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();

            // Set the height of the Item View
            params.height = 60;
            view.setLayoutParams(params);

            //TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            tv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            tv.setTextSize(15);
            //tv.setHeight(15);
             return view;
        }
    };
    setListAdapter(mBTAdapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);` to `onViewCreated`.

Can you try moving the code where you set the items in the adapter to `onViewCreated` as well?

Comment: thank you. I've moved the getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this) to onViewCreated. but getting error "content view not yet created"

Comment: Can you try moving the code where you set the items in the adapter to `onViewCreated` as well?